# Cannot read property 'image' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

Cannot read property 'image' of null at module.exports

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
if (!req.files.image) {
    return res.redirect('/posts/new')
}

next()}
```

index.js :

```
const express = require('express')

const app = new express()

const path = require('path')

const expressEdge = require('express-edge')

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const Post = require('./database/models/Post')

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')



mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/node-js-blog', { useNewUrlParser:       true })

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(fileUpload())

app.use(expressEdge)

app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`)

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}))

const storePost = require('./middleware/storePosts')
app.use('/posts/store', storePost)

app.get('/',async (req, res)=>{
const posts = await Post.find({})
console.log(posts)
res.render('index',{
    posts
})
})

app.get('/about', (req,res)=>{
res.render('about')
})

app.get('/post/:id', async (req,res)=>{
const post = await Post.findById(req.params.id)
res.render('post',{
    post
})
})

app.get('/contact', (req,res)=>{
res.render('contact')
})

app.get('/posts/new', (req,res)=>{
res.render('create')
})

app.post("/posts/store", (req, res) => {
const {image} = req.files

image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/posts', image.name), (error) => {
    Post.create({
        ...req.body,
        image: `/posts/${image.name}`
    }, (error, post) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
})
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
console.log('start server')
})
```

create.edge:

```
<div class="form-group mt-5">
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file">
                  </div>
```

when i use middleware.js to headlining not inserting image it give me this error when user not upload image file and return TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null
    at module.exports (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/middleware/storePosts.js:2:20)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at urlencodedParser (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:100:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:119:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/mohamedessam/Desktop/NodeJs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7.

Comment: `req.files` is null, so you cannot access the image property of a null object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Update (June 2022)

Since [Ecma262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/), which came out after this anwser, the [safe operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is available in javascript, and supported by most modern browsers. It may be too early to call it widely supported, but it makes the syntax way more friendly (and it should work fine in recent versions of Node).

```js
if (!req?.files?.image) {
 // ...
}
```

## Original Answer (July 2019)

Thats because you always directly check for the sub-property `image`, but at some point you didn’t set the `req.files` in which it is nested. Since `req.files` doesn’t exist, it returns a null type, which javascript cannot parse.

You first need to check if all parent key exist individually, in javascript, to test the existence of a nested key in an object. The following should fix the issue :

```js
if (!(req.files && req.files.image))
```

Answer (score -1):

as the javascript is case sensitive, you should give the exact name as used in the form for the image